# How to write EF query for Common Table Expression

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

This Sql query returns the expected data. I need to do the same in EF Query. I am not sure how to do it all in one EF query.

```
WITH cteproductactions (productkey, actionid) AS (
    SELECT productkey, count(*) FROM productactions
    GROUP BY productkey
    HAVING count(*)>0
)
SELECT p.name,p.productkey,p.imageurl
FROM product p
INNER JOIN cteproductactions c on p.ProductKey=c.productkey
WHERE p.profileid=100
```

EF Query

```
var products = productRepo.Where(x => x.profileid=100);
var productkeys = products.Select(x => x.ProductKey).ToList();
var productActions = productActionsRepo.Where(x => productkeys.Contains(x.ProductKey));
```

Comment: fixed it, it was a typo, I manually typed it here

Comment: EF does not support CTEs, to my knowledge. EF is great when it works - but painful and awkward when you fall into it’s many feature-support-gaps. All I can suggest is you define your CTE as a VIEW and then reference the view in your DbContext.

Comment: You can just remove the `ToList` and bam, you have a single query.  You went out of your way to intentionally turn the one query into two in the first place.

Comment: To expand on @Dai's comment, EF Core handles this scenario with a keyless entity type. 

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations

Create a view that returns the result of your CTE and configure that view as a keyless entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll tie yourself in knots trying to write an SQL then "converting" it into LINQ or forcing EF to generate an SQL that is the same.. It's better to start from a place where you express what you want in high level (English) and write the LINQ for it; forget the SQL unless there's a real problem

The SQL as written doesn't really make sense, or need a CTE, the HAVING clause is pointless and none of the columns from the CTE are used in the output. The only purpose the CTE serves is to filter the product list down to those that have at least one productkey, so write an EF from that - "all products Where profile is is 100 and a related product key exists" - don't get bogged down in "how do I make EF do a cte?" because these SQL express the same sentiments without a CTE:

```
SELECT p.name,p.productkey,p.imageurl
FROM product p
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT productKey FROM productactions) c on p.ProductKey=c.productkey
WHERE p.profileid=100
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.name,p.productkey,p.imageurl
FROM product p
INNER JOIN productactions c on p.ProductKey=c.productkey
WHERE p.profileid=100
```

```
SELECT p.name,p.productkey,p.imageurl
FROM product p
WHERE p.profileid=100
  AND EXISTS(SELECT null FROM productactions c WHERE p.ProductKey=c.productkey)
```

Assuming product and productactions are in a 1:M relationship connected by productKey, consider something like:

```
var products = productRepo
  .Where(p => p.profileid==100 && p.ProductActions.Any())
  .Select(p => new {p.Name, p.ProductKey, p.ImageUrl)
```

Main message here is "don't start from an SQL mindset and think "how can I make EF do this sql", start from a "What do I want and how can I make EF do it" - forget the SQL unless EF is generating something horrifically underperformant.

Comment: I accept this as answer but I did it like this
"from product in productRepo
join d in productActionsRepo on product.ProductKey equals d.ProductKey
select new {
Name=product.Name,
ProductKey=product.ProductKey,
ImageUrl=product.ImageUrl
}"
And, as you said, the CTE was unnecessary, I realized it.